# Is there any way in android through which i can play two audio at the same time in android ? one on my app and one on another background app

Tags: java, android

Is there any way in android through which i can play two audio at the same time in Android?

For example if a song is playing in background say on spotify and I have to play some audio in my app , then both should be played( maybe dimming spotify's audio) instead of pausing spotify ?

Normally what happens is if we play audio on one app , the other app's audio get's paused, how to make them play simultaneously.